# DateTime Converted to Invalid Format

Tags: c#, datetime

I tried converting 9/29/2013 2:44:28 PM (mm/dd/yyyy) to dd/mm/yyyy format.

I got a strange Date after Converting.

I tried

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy");

29/44/2013
```

The Date was a type of `DateTime` itself.

Comment: Show your complete code.. And what is your `Culture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül I added the code I tried

Comment: I think 'mm' should be in capital letters

Comment: I doubt that you get a strange date - I'd think you get an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MM` is for months, `mm` is for minutes. That's why it gets your minutes (which is `44`) instead of your month value.

Use it like;

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Check out;

- [`The "MM" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier)
- [`The "mm" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier)

And remember, `/` has special meaning when you use it as a date separator. It replace itself with your current culture date separator. Forcing to use with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) would be better.

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Take a look at;

- [`The "/" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> What if I want to convert a string in dd/MM/yyyy to DateTime?

Then you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.

As an example;

```
string s = "01/01/2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/P7CVbM)</kbd>.

Comment: What if I want to convert a string in dd/MM/yyyy to DateTime?

Comment: @SubinJacob Updated in my answer.

Comment: @SubinJacob You tried my complete code? This should work. Are you sure? What is your `Culture` by the way.

Comment: you see, you got `1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM` (`string`)  and it cannot be converted back to DateTime. How this can be done?

Comment: @SubinJacob `1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM` is already `DateTime` (called with `dt`) You are trying convert to `DateTime` to `DateTime`.

Comment: No, when I converted `DateTime` in MM/dd/yyyy format to dd/MM/yyyy format and then to string it would be `1/1/2013` (see single digits). I can't convert this string back to `DateTime` (from dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: Use `d` format instead of `dd` format then. `d` is for 0-31, `dd` is for 01-31. Please read [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) where you can find all informations.

Answer (score 9):

Lowercase `mm` means  minutes, try this instead:

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

However, if this works depends on your local culture. If your current culture's date separator is different, `/` will be replaced with that. So if you want to enforce it use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:`

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dateTimeVar.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"); // Change to dd/MM/yyyy
```

The problem is `mm` stands for minute and you need `MM` which would be months

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is correct, but to remove the format string altogether you can use. 'ToShortDateString'

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

var stringDate = date.ToShortDateString();
var stringDate2 = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```